# Schema - Ability to change email address (primary user id) in Django

Tags: python, django, database, schema

Currently my  user table looks like this - (all fields are not null)

```
display_name  = CharField                  # string
email_address = EmailField   (primary key) # string
password      = CharField                  # string
```

However, I have decided to add additional functionality and to allow users to change their email addresses.

The flow goes like this

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Currently I am thinking of something like

```
display_name  = CharField                  # string
email_address = EmailField   (primary key) # string
password      = CharField                  # string
pending_email = EmailField   (unique)      # string
```

And simply hold the new email address in `pending_email` before replacing the old email address in `email_address`

But obviously this is far from perfect (e.g. `pending_email` unique constraint does not cover `email_address`)

Ive thought about just leaving it like this and performing more selects against the database with AJAX queries to check if the desired new email address already lives in `email_address` before allowing it to be entered into `pending_email` but this seems still vulnerable to race conditions and poor user experiences on top of being not very database friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard practice in this sort of situation is to create a separate table for email addresses. That allows users to have more than one email address at a given time and one of them can be marked as default.

This is what [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py#L23)'s EmailAddress model looks like. In fact, unless you have a very compelling reason to write your own authentication system, I highly recommend that your swith to django allauth or any of the widely used django authentication/registration system.

```
class EmailAddress(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(allauth_app_settings.USER_MODEL,
                             verbose_name=_('user'))
    email = models.EmailField(unique=app_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL,
                              max_length=app_settings.EMAIL_MAX_LENGTH,
                              verbose_name=_('e-mail address'))
    verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('verified'), default=False)
    primary = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('primary'), default=False)

    objects = EmailAddressManager()
```